# How to remove spesific things from data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data like this:

```
draft_round
    0   1st round
    1   3rd round
    2   1st round
    3   16th round
    4   2nd round
    ... ...
    4680    1st round
    4681    NaN
    4682    2nd round
    4683    2nd round
    4684    1947 BAA Draf
```

As you can see, each row of data has complex data, a combination of words and numbers. The important thing for me here is to get the numbers in these lines. For example, I want to get the number "1" in a data row named "1st round" and "16" in a data row "16th round". In other words, I want the yield to be as follows:

```
      draft_round
        0   1
        1   3
        2   1
        3   16
        4   2
        ... ...
        4680    1
        4681    NaN
        4682    2
        4683    20
        4684    1947 BAA Draf
```

I hope I was able to explain my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use sub from the re library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try **str.split** :

```
df['draft_round'] = df['draft_round'].str.split(pat='[a-z]', expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: This was very useful sir, thank you. But some data like "1968 NBA D" did not removed. Do you know something about this?

Comment: that data looks irrelevant to 'draft_round'. you can simply drop that row of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.str.replace`:

```py
df["draft_round"] = df["draft_round"].str.replace(
    r"(\d+).*round", r"\1", regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        draft_round
0                 1
1                 3
2                 1
3                16
4                 2
4680              1
4681            NaN
4682              2
4683              2
4684  1947 BAA Draf
```

Comment: I'm very thankful sir, thanks for you help.I just learned something new from you.